# What is the technical difference between core-data and SQLite and usage?

Tags: sqlite, core-data

> Can anyone explain me what is the tech difference between them . What
>   I know about that core data is a wrapper over SQLite and Internally it
>   uses SQLite.
>
> If Core data Internally uses SQLite then how Core Data is faster then
>   SQLite and why we use core data in most of the application?

Please explain it with the relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a database.  It fundamentally stores data organized as tables of similar data broken up into rows of individual data items.

CoreData is an object store.  It stores an arbitrary graph of many objects and their connections between each other.  That it uses SQLite is ancillary to it's real function, it could (and does) just as easily store that graph in an XML file, a property list file, or other arbitrary data formats.

As for why you use CoreData instead of SQLite, it's primarily simplicity.  With SQLite you have to deal with reading the rows from the tables and reconstructing individual useful objects.  With CoreData, that's all transparently handled for you, as well as a great many other issues like inter-thread synchronization and migration (changes from version to version).

Comment: To put it bluntly, I've never seen anyone use SQLite correctly without several emergency patch releases and a few maintenance releases.  That includes the CoreData team itself.   :).

Comment: Eh, I've never seen somebody implement `CoreData` correctly the first time either, the each have their complexities.  With `CoreData` it centers on thread consistency and they've done a lot of work to make that aspect of it easier to use.

Comment: The is as the option to go straight to the XML by using `NSKeyedArchiver`. I'm moving to NSCoder/XML/GZIP right now, I've had quite enough of both SQLite and CoreData.